# Refer to memory location with an offset in GNU Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, offset, gnu, gnu-assembler

Sorry in advance for the novice question, but strangely enough I couldn't find a proper answer to this question. Simply put, let's say I want to movl from a certain variable to the %ecx register. This variable is a buffer full of input. How do I reference the buffer AT a specific offset, ie buffer + 1 or buffer + n? I need it for basic string iteration.

All help is appreciated, even if it's just helping me find a previous post that answers it but that I couldn't find.

Comment: That's not a register that you are asking about, that's a variable. And you refer to it exactly like you showed: `movl buffer + 1, %ecx`. If the offset is not constant you load it into a register and use something like `movl buffer(%eax), %ecx`. This is basic knowledge you should read some introductory material. PS: for strings you probably want to use a 8 bit destination or `movzbl`/`movsbl`.

Comment: @Jester For one, I don't have access to any introductory material proper, the one book I have on assembly is in x86 architecture. So it is literally just [variableName] + [offset]?

Comment: You should be careful about `[]` notation because that has its own meaning in intel syntax. I have showed you the example, that's how it should look. See also the [as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html).

Comment: Please do not remove architecture tag.

Comment: Does this apply to x86 as well? If so I have no problem, but the question is about GAS assembly.

Comment: It applies to x86, other architectures may use different addressing.

Comment: Also, how do I use the contents of a register instead of a number as the offset?

Comment: I have **showed** you an example for that too!

Comment: Ok, ok, yeesh. I didn't notice it, I'm getting frustrated that what little assembly instruction I can find with Google is never in a format that I can understand and it's making me weird. I'll try that. EDIT: Ok, it works now. Thank you for your help, the manual you linked me to I simply could not understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AT&T syntax (used by GAS), the following is used for an indirect offset reference:

```
 movl     8(%ebp), %eax   ; Move from EBP+8 into EAX
```

In Intel syntax (Which is actually also understood and accepted by GAS) it would be:

```
 MOV      EAX, [EBP+8]
```

Another alternative (which you seem to be interested in) is Base Plus Index addressing:

```
 MOV      EAX, [EBX + EDI]
```

This moves into EAX (using Intel format) the content of the memory location that is the sum of EBX and EDI.  In AT&T format this would be:

```
 movl     (%ebx,%edi), %eax
```

Honestly, I rarely use this form.  You may have to include a scale factor.  You can use one to meet your needs:

```
 movl     (%ebx,%edi,1),%eax   ; Where 1 is a scaling factor (ebx+edi*scale)
```

Comment: Could you show me your first example, but instead of 8 use a register that contains the offset number?

Comment: I've added some examples that ought to work.  Might need adjusting.  I rarely write code quite that way and I avoid AT&T syntax whenever possible. :)

Comment: I still seem to have trouble. Here, I'll show the code that's having issues: `movl $buffer, %edi - movl (%edi,%esi), %ecx` The contents of %esi are incremented in a loop that I know works, and movl $buffer, %edi is called at the beginning of the loop every time. However, it doesn't increment the index properly to be one after another, and seems to randomly jump around. Am I doing it right?

Comment: It sounds to me as though you have an entirely different problem that needs debugging.  I think the question you have here is a good one and you should leave it as is since it's been answered.  I'd open a new question, posting your code and asking what you just said to me here... "I can't see why this index is jumping around randomly.  What have I missed??"